# Why do I need 17 significant digits (and not 16) to represent a double?

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, ieee-754, floating-accuracy

Can someone give me an example of a floating point number (double precision), that needs more than 16 significant decimal digits to represent it?

I have found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738768/printing-double-without-losing-precision) that sometimes you need up to 17 digits, but I am not able to find an example of such a number (16 seems enough to me).

Can somebody clarify this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My other answer was dead wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned long long n = 1ULL << 53;
    unsigned long long a = 2*(n-1);
    unsigned long long b = 2*(n-2);
    printf("%llu\n%llu\n%d\n", a, b, (double)a == (double)b);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run to see:

```
18014398509481982
18014398509481980
0
```

a and b are just 2*(2<sup>53</sup>-1) and 2*(2<sup>53</sup>-2).

Those are 17-digit base-10 numbers.  When rounded to 16 digits, they are the same.  Yet a and b clearly only need 53 bits of precision to represent in base-2.  So if you take a and b and cast them to double, you get your counter-example.

Comment: I have edited your program a bit. It now prints the two different double precision numbers: 1.8014398509481982e+16
1.8014398509481980e+16   Thanks a lot, this is the right answer!

Comment: I also posted a simple Fortran program below, showing that indeed 17 digits is needed.

Comment: Btw, here is a simple way to proof why we need 17 digits: If the smallest double that can be added to 1 is epsilon ~ 2e-16, then
1+epsilon = 1.0000000000000002, which obviously requires 17 digits to represent.

Comment: %Lu is non-standard. %llu should be used instead.

Comment: @BSalita: Indeed you are correct (and I have learned something today). Fixed; thanks.

Comment: Good answer to show that at least 17 significant decimal digits needed.  A stronger case is needed to show that only 17 needed.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Any idea for a stronger case or proof?

Comment: @chenzhongpu Consider 1 followed by 16 zeros.  The log2(1000....) is 53.15.....  A proof could exploit this edge case.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is the one by Nemo above. Here I am just pasting a simple Fortran program showing an example of the two numbers, that need 17 digits of precision to print, showing, that one does need `(es23.16)` format to print double precision numbers, if one doesn't want to loose any precision:

```
program test
implicit none
integer, parameter :: dp = kind(0.d0)
real(dp) :: a, b
a = 1.8014398509481982e+16_dp
b = 1.8014398509481980e+16_dp
print *, "First we show, that we have two different 'a' and 'b':"
print *, "a == b:", a == b, "a-b:", a-b
print *, "using (es22.15)"
print "(es22.15)", a
print "(es22.15)", b
print *, "using (es23.16)"
print "(es23.16)", a
print "(es23.16)", b
end program
```

it prints:

```
First we show, that we have two different 'a' and 'b':
a == b: F a-b:   2.0000000000000000     
using (es22.15)
1.801439850948198E+16
1.801439850948198E+16
using (es23.16)
1.8014398509481982E+16
1.8014398509481980E+16
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the guy on that thread is wrong, and 16 base-10 digits are always enough to represent an IEEE double.

My attempt at a proof would go something like this:

Suppose otherwise.  Then, necessarily, two distinct double-precision numbers must be represented by the same 16-significant-digit base-10 number.

But two distinct double-precision numbers must differ by at least one part in 2<sup>53</sup>, which is greater than one part in 10<sup>16</sup>.  And no two numbers differing by more than one part in 10<sup>16</sup> could possibly round to the same 16-significant-digit base-10 number.

This is not completely rigorous and could be wrong.  :-)

Comment: Nice argument. I am putting this as the right answer, unless somebody actually provides a counter argument (some number that doesn't work). Here is the code in Python (the formatting is not great): `In [1]: 2**(-53)
Out[1]: 1.1102230246251565e-16

In [2]: 10**(-16)                                                              
Out[2]: 9.9999999999999998e-17
`

Comment: Unfortunately, I now think I am wrong...  Suppose we only had three bits of mantissa.  By my argument, that should correspond to one base-10 digit.  But now consider 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, and 14 (i.e., 2 times 1,2,3,...7).  Those are clearly three-bit mantissas, but 10, 12, and 14 are all the same when rounded to one significant digit.  I will try to construct a "double" counterexample later today.  (Great question, btw)

Comment: Indeed, your other answer nailed this down. So I put that one as the correct answer. Thanks a lot for this, I really appreciate your effort. So now it is clear, that if I want to print doubles, I do need to use `%.16e` in C, or `(es23.16)` in Fortran.

Answer (score 0):

Dig into the single and double precision basics and wean yourself of the notion of this or that (16-17) many DECIMAL digits and start thinking in (53) BINARY digits. The necessary examples may be found here at stackoverflow if you spend some time digging.

And I fail to see how you can award a best answer to anyone giving a DECIMAL answer without qualified BINARY explanations. This stuff is straight-forward but it is not trivial.

Comment: Hi Olof, thanks for your answer. I have searched through the stackoverflow very carefully, but wasn't able to find the answer to my question. Could you please point me to some examples of that?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738768/printing-double-without-losing-precision/4851671#4851671) should provide you with some insight into why floating point values (seem to) "behave stangely" (they don't). I'll try to find some more.

Comment: [Here's another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827176/how-to-distinguish-between-1-and-zero-floating-point-values/4844572#4844572) and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327020/why-are-floating-point-values-so-prolific/4164252#4164252)

Comment: @Ondrej Certik: so how did you get along with the binary angle on floating point decimals?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointers. In fact, I have read all these posts before asking here, because I couldn't find an example of a number that needs 17 digits. The accepted answer at this question answers this.

Comment: Voyager space travel? South Korean National accounting? Indonesian National accounting? Accounting programs do not store values as floating point dollars.cents (for example) instead they use cents: when the values need to be displayed they use value/100.value%100. My point is that floating point is not good for exact values unless you leave out the fraction part and, if you do, you get fewer significant digits than if you were to use integers. The US public debt (today) is 15,071,624,794,970.66 - that's 16 digits. Significant digit requirements have a way of sneaking up on and biting you :)

Answer (score 0):

The largest continuous range of integers that can be exactly represented by a double (8-byte IEEE) is -2<sup>53</sup> to 2<sup>53</sup> (-9007199254740992. to 9007199254740992.). The numbers -2<sup>53</sup>-1 and 2<sup>53</sup>+1 cannot be exactly represented by a double.

Therefore, no more than 16 significant decimal digits to the left of the decimal point will exactly represent a double in the continuous range.