# double and stringstream formatting

Tags: c++, double

```
double val = 0.1;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << val;
std::string strVal= ss.str();
```

In the Visual Studio debugger, `val` has the value 0.10000000000000001 (because 0.1 can't be represented).
When `val` is converted using stringstream, `strVal` is equal to `"0.1"`. However, when using boost::lexical_cast, the resulting `strVal` is `"0.10000000000000001"`.

Another example is the following:

`double val = 12.12305000012;`

Under visual studio `val` appears as 12.123050000119999, and using stringstream and default precision (6) it becomes 12.1231. I don't really understand why it is not 12.12305(...).

Is there a default precision, or does stringstream have a particular algorithm to convert a double value which can't be exactly represented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can change the floating-point precision of a `stringstream` as follows:

```
double num = 2.25149;
std::stringstream ss(stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
ss << std::setprecision(5) << num << endl;
ss << std::setprecision(4) << num << endl;
```

Output:

```
2.2515
2.251
```

Note how the numbers are also rounded when appropriate.

Comment: in testing this in Visual Studio C++, I can only get this to work by calling `ss.setf(ios::fixed);` first.  If I don't do that, then the precision does not change.

Comment: use `std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10)` to get full double precision.

Comment: `digits10` does not work, at least on Visual Studio 2015. Try `18014398509481980.0` and `18014398509481982.0`. 17 is the minimum for full precision. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6118231/280534 and try it at https://onlinegdb.com/Sk6yXmeY7

Comment: **cppreference** points out [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) the max precision is attained with: `std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 + 1)`

Comment: You can also use [`std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10) since C++11, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22458961 for the difference between `std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10` and `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10`.

Answer (score 18):

For anyone who gets "`error: ‘setprecision’ is not a member of ‘std’`" you must `#include <iomanip>` else `setprecision(17)` will not work!

Comment: This should be a comment, or an edit of an existing answer.

Comment: @MarkIngram I'm very sorry, this will not happen again.

Answer (score 5):

There are two issues you have to consider.  The first is the precision
parameter, which defaults to 6 (but which you can set to whatever you
like).  The second is what this parameter means, and that depends on the
format option you are using: if you are using fixed or scientific 
format, then it means the number of digits after the decimal (which in
turn has a different effect on what is usually meant by precision in the
two formats); if you are using the default precision, however (`ss.setf(
std::ios_base::fmtflags(), std::ios_base::formatfield )`, it means the
number of **digits** in the output, regardless of whether the output was
actually formatted using scientific or fixed notation.  This explains
why your display is `12.1231`, for example; you're using both the
default precision and the default formattting.

You might want to try the following with different values (and maybe
different precisions):

```
std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::fmtflags(), std::ios_base::floatfield );
std::cout << "default:    " << value[i] << std::endl;
std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield );
std::cout << "fixed:      " << value[i] << std::endl;
std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::scientific, std::ios_base::floatfield );
std::cout << "scientific: " << value[i] << std::endl;
```

Seeing the actual output will probably be clearer than any detailed description:

```
default:    0.1
fixed:      0.100000
scientific: 1.000000e-01
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem occurs at the stream insertion `ss << 0.1;` rather than at the conversion to string. If you want non-default precision you need to specify this prior to inserting the double:

```
ss << std::setprecision(17) << val;
```

On my computer, if I just use `setprecision(16)` I still get `"0.1"` rather than `"0.10000000000000001"`. I need a (slightly bogus) precision of 17 to see that final 1.

**Addendum**
A better demonstration arises with a value of 1.0/3.0. With the default precision you get a string representation of `"0.333333"`. This is not the string equivalent of a double precision 1/3. Using `setprecision(16)` makes the string `"0.3333333333333333"`; a precision of 17 yields `"0.33333333333333331"`.

Comment: I have tried with the following real 12.12305000012, in computer under visual studio it appears has 12.123050000119999 and using stringstream and default precision(6 isn't it?) it becomes 12.1231. I don't really understand why it it not 12.12305(..something)

Comment: To six decimal places, 12.12305000012 *is* 12.1231. This rounding takes place at the insertion into the stream. You can control this rounding behavior via `setprecision` -- or you can simply use `Boost::lexical_cast`. `Boost::lexical_cast` also uses string streams, but it specifies the precision on insertion to try to ensure that nothing is lost. For floating point types, `lexical_cast` uses a bit more than the maximum precision so as to minimize losses.

Comment: ok because precision of 6 mean the total number of digit used, not the number of decimal

Comment: Yep. What `setprecision` does depends on the setting of the stream's `floatfield`. This can be `fixed`, `scientific`, or (none). `setprecision(<p>)` behaves similarly to the `"%.<p>f"` format specifier in the C `printf` family of functions for `fixed`, `"%.<p>e" for `scientific`, and `"%.<p>g"` for (none).