# Matlab vs C++ Double Precision

Tags: c++, matlab, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

I am porting some code from Matlab to C++.

**In Matlab**

```
format long
D = 0.689655172413793 (this is 1.0 / 1.45)
E = 2600 / D
// I get E = 3.770000000000e+03
```

**In C++**

```
double D = 0.68965517241379315; //(this is 1.0 / 1.45)
double E = 2600 / D;
//I get E = 3769.9999999999995
```

It is a problem for me because in both cases I have to do rounding down to 0 (Matlab's fix), and in the first case (Matlab) is becomes 3770, whereas in the second case (C++) it becomes 3769.

I realise that it is because of the two additional least significant digits "15" in the C++ case. Given that Matlab seems to only store up to 15 significant digits of precision in double precision (as shown above - 0.689655172413793), how can I effectively tell C++ to ignore the "15" at the back?

All calculations are done in double precision.

Comment: Where does the value of `D` come from? Why don't you just multiply `2600*1.45`?

Comment: floats and their representations are always a problem; you're calculating 20/29 ... that's not fitting any of precesitions, either in base2 nor in base10

Comment: take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error#Representation_error
perhaps a library implementing fractions could help you

Comment: Ok, so three words, just don't. In case precision to the 17th decimal is required, you should definitely handle this more sophisticated. Find out why you need to do it the way you do and rewrite it in a safe way. Apart from this, Matlab and c++ follows the same standard. See answers below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You got confused by the different ways C++ and MATLAB are printing double values. MATLAB's [`format long`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html#inputarg_style) only prints 15 [significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) while C++ prints 17 [significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures). Internally both use the same numbers: [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) 64 bit floating point numbers. To reproduce the C++-behaviour in MATLAB, I defined a [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) `disp17` which prints numbers with 17 significant digits:

```
>> disp17=@(x)(disp(num2str(x,17)))

disp17 = 

    @(x)(disp(num2str(x,17)))

>> 1.0 / 1.45

ans =

   0.689655172413793

>> disp17(1.0 / 1.45)
0.68965517241379315
```

You see the result in MATLAB and C++ is the same, they just print a different number of digits. If you now continue in both programming languages with the same constant, you get the same result.

```
>> D = 0.68965517241379315 %17 digits, enough to represent a double.

D =

   0.689655172413793

>> ans = 2600 / D %Result looks wrong

ans =

     3.770000000000000e+03

>> disp17(2600 / D) %But displaying 17 digits it is the same.
3769.9999999999995
```

The background for printing 17 or 15 digits:

- [A double requires 17 significant digits to be stored without precision loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118231/why-do-i-need-17-significant-digits-and-not-16-to-represent-a-double), which is what C prints.
- For up to 15 digits any number can be converted from string to double to string and results back in the original number, which is what MATLAB does.

Answer (score -3):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve, using `ceil` function might help:

```
ans = ceil(ans); /* smallest integral value that is not less than ans. */
// now ans in C++ is also be 3970.
```

Here is [usage reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/).

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is looking for.