# Subtracting two equal floating-point numbers in MATLAB is not equal 0

Tags: matlab, floating-point, precision

Suppose we want to calculate (a + b)<sup>2</sup> in two different ways, that is

1. (a + b) * (a + b)
2. a<sup>2</sup> + 2 a b + b<sup>2</sup>

Now, suppose `a = 1.4` and `b = -2.7`. If we plug those two numbers  in the formulas with `format long` we obtain in both cases `1.690000000000001`, that is, if I run the following script:

```
a = 1.4; 
b = -2.7;

format long

r = (a + b) * (a + b)

r2 = a^2 + 2*a*b + b^2

abs_diff = abs(r - r2)
```

I obtain

```
r = 1.690000000000001

r2 = 1.690000000000001

abs_diff = 6.661338147750939e-16
```

What's going on here? I could preview different results for `r` or `r2` (because Matlab would be executing different floating-point operations), but not for the absolute value of their difference.

I also noticed that the relative error of `r` and `r2` are different, that is, if I do

```
rel_err1 = abs(1.69 - r) / 1.69
rel_err2 = abs(1.69 - r2) / 1.69
```

I obtain

```
rel_err1 = 3.941620205769786e-16

rel_err2 = 7.883240411539573e-16
```

This only makes me think that `r` are not actually the same `r2`. Is there a way to see them completely then, if they are really different? If not, what's happening?

Also, both relative errors are not less than `eps / 2`, does this mean that an overflow has happened? If yes, where?

---

Note: This is a specific case. I understood that we're dealing with floating-point numbers and rounding errors. But I would like a to understand better them by going through this example.

Comment: It's likely due to the fact that floating point errors depends on the *order*,  *type* and *number* of operations. Your two methods have different number and types of operations. The one with [more additions theoretically introduces](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/propagation/) more floating point errors. Also more operations causes more propagation of the error.

Comment: @Suever My intuition was that since both methods are actually implemented differently, i.e. using different floating-point operations, then we would obtain different results, and this would explain that their difference is different from 0 (anyway). But Matlab apparently represents `r` and `r2` in the same way, so their difference should be 0...

Comment: what in your post demonstrates that MATLAB represents `r` and `r2` in the same way?

Comment: @Suever The fact that `r` and `r2` are both represented as `1.690000000000001`

Comment: Simple answer: your two numbers are *not* equal. The long format is only giving you 16 significant digits, which isn't enough to distinguish these two numbers. Their exact values are `1.6900000000000006128431095930864103138446807861328125` and `1.690000000000001278976924368180334568023681640625`, both of which are exactly representable as IEEE 754 binary floats, and both of which display as `1.690000000000001` when rounded to 16 significant (decimal) digits.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks, you went to the point. But is there a way in Matlab to show more digits? Because indeed it's misleading...

Comment: @nbro: No idea, I'm afraid. I'm not a MATLAB user, just a floating-point enthusiast.

Comment: `format hex` will show you the actual binary representation of the numbers.  In this case, they are 3ffb0a3d70a3d70d and 3ffb0a3d70a3d710 for r and r2 respectively.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Pretty much the same way you would anywhere else: `fprintf("%.60f\n",r)`

Comment: @beaker: Good to know; thanks. In that case, a format of `"%.17g"` should be enough to distinguish any two distinct IEEE 754 doubles. 16 significant digits is *almost* enough, but it's one digit short for the purposes of giving a faithful representation.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Also good to know. Thanks :)

Comment: @beaker Thanks, and feel free to add it as an answer, 'cause it's more visible also for future users ;)

Comment: nbro, you could write the answer and incorporate @KylerBrown's suggestion as well.

Comment: @beaker Ok, maybe I will give an answer that englobes what you guys have been saying if nobody decides to do it ;)

Comment: To track floating point issues, format long is not sufficient. You must print 17 digits http://stackoverflow.com/a/35626253/2732801 . Maybe that helps to understand the behaviour.

Comment: @MarkDickinson How would you explain the fact that the absolute error (for both `r` and `r2`) is greater than eps / 2 (that is the machine precision divided by 2)?

Comment: @nbro: Why shouldn't it be? Every arithmetic operation you perform might introduce some error, and the computation of `r` (or `r2`) involves several operations: the errors accumulate. And the bound on the error for a single operation is more easily expressed in terms of relative error rather than absolute; even then, it's not as simple as `eps / 2`: you need to take the quantization of the binary format into account. If you want to do some reading, you might try the [Handbook of Floating Point Arithmetic](http://www.springer.com/jp/book/9780817647049).

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ok, thanks! I don't think I will have the time soon, but maybe in the future I will have a look at it ;)

Answer (score 3):

Don't rely on the output of `format long` to conclude that two numbers are equal...

```
a = 1.4;
b = -2.7
r1 = (a + b) * (a + b);
r2 = a^2 + 2*a*b + b^2;
r3 = (a+b)^2;
```

Instead you can check their hex representation using:

```
>> num2hex([r1 r2 r3])
ans =
3ffb0a3d70a3d70d
3ffb0a3d70a3d710
3ffb0a3d70a3d70d
```

or the `printf` family of functions:

```
>> fprintf('%bx\n', r1, r2, r3)
3ffb0a3d70a3d70d
3ffb0a3d70a3d710
3ffb0a3d70a3d70d
```

or even:

```
>> format hex
>> disp([r1; r2; r3])
   3ffb0a3d70a3d70d
   3ffb0a3d70a3d710
   3ffb0a3d70a3d70d
```

Comment: What about the suggestion of using `fprintf` to print a floating-point number with as many decimal digits as we want, e.g., `fprintf('%.60f', my_float);`?

Comment: I would always trust the hex representation more because that's the actual 1's and 0's stored, no rounding involved... Not to mention, how far will you go with `fprintf` if `my_float = realmin` for example?

Answer (score 1):

[Floating point arithmetic is not associative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430448/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-aaaaaa-to-aaaaaa).

While mathematically these two are equal, they are not in floating point maths.

```
r = (a + b) * (a + b)

r2 = a^2 + 2*a*b + b^2
```

The order operations are executed in floating point maths is very relevant. That is why when you do floating point maths you need to be very careful of the order of you r multiplications/divisions, specially when working with very big numbers together with really small numbers.

Comment: Ok, but if `r` and `r2` are represent in memory apparently with the same number, their absolute difference would be equal to zero...