# find in array of datetimes

Tags: matlab, date, floating-point

I have two excel files with dates in each of them. The goal is to find the location  of datetimes in file A in file B.

e.g.
Excel file A has dates and each hour in column A from 1Jan1970 1AM to 31Dec2015 1AM with a lot of random missing dates and hour.

Excel file B has date e.g. 1jan1978 5PM

I read file A in array called A and do the following:

```
ind = find( x2mdate(A) == x2mdate(28491.7083333333) ); %datestr(x2mdate(28491.7083333333)) ans = 01-Jan-1978 17:00:00
```

it returns empty even though I can see that 1/1/1978 all hours are available in file A.

This is clearly a rounding issue. So, how do I deal with this? I tried using `datestr` but it is very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing to the wrong value. `28491.7083333333` is slightly off the value you are looking for. When you want to use a precise match with constant floats, [you have to use 17 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35626253/2732801). Otherwise compare with a reasonable tolerance.

```
tol=datenum(0,0,0,0,0,60) %60 seconds tolerance
ind = find( abs(x2mdate(A) - x2mdate(28491.7083333333)<tol );
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `x2mdate(28491.7083333333)`, try using:

```
datenum('01-Jan-1978 17:00:00', 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS')
```

It's easy to see that because of the rounding, they are not considered equal:

```
>> datenum('01-Jan-1978 17:00:00', 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS') == x2mdate(28491.7083333333)
ans =
     0
```