# Matlab, k = 1.000000000000000 but k == 1 returns 0

Tags: matlab, floating-point

I already read [the other discussion here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab) but I still cannot understand why the code does not work as expected.

In my code I check that `k` is approximately equal to `1`, but still it does not work:

```matlab
if approx(k, 1, eps)
    display('Approx equal');
else
    k
    k == 1
    approx(k, 1, eps)
    abs(k - 1) < eps
end
```

Instead of displaying the string, this is the result (I have enabled `format long`):

```
k = 1.000000000000000
ans = 0
ans = 0
ans = 0
```

This is baffling! I also tried to increase the error by `k * 1e20` but the result is still `1e20`... What to do here?

Note: although not really relevant to the question, here is the definition of `approx`:

```matlab
function r = approx(a, b, tol)
    r = a <= b + tol && a >= b - tol;
end
```

EDIT: I changed the `approx` function to avoid catastrophic cancellation:

```matlab
function r = approx(a, b, tol)
    r = a <= b + tol && a + tol >= b; % assumes tol is positive
end
```

Comment: I might just point out that I cannot reproduce this (R2015a OS X 64-bit). What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: @dfri I'm using R2015b on Windows 32-bit.

Comment: Please change your code to print at least 17 significant digits, this will allow us to reproduce your problem. Code to print 17 significant digits can be found [in my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35626253/2732801)

Comment: @Daniel Oh, indeed it is `k = 0.99999999999999967`.

Comment: @dfri I removed the subtraction from `approx` (now it's `r <= b + tol && a + tol >= b`) and found that `approx(k, 1, 1e-15) = 1` but `approx(k, 1, 1e-16) = 0`. And since `eps ~ 2e-16` I was considering using `approx(k, 1, 10*eps)` in my ifs. Does that sound right?

Comment: @rubik: We don't know you application and how large the errors can be, but setting `tol` to the maximum possible error which can happen is probably the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try displaying:

```
k - 1.000000000000000
```

I think you will find that there is a tiny but non-zero residual value.