# Export from Matlab to Stata an array of numbers and strings

Tags: arrays, matlab, stata

I need to export from Matlab to Stata an array of numbers and strings.

For example:

```
clear

r=2;
n=4;
X=unifrnd(0,1,r,n);

X_STATA=reshape(X.', r*n,1);
id_STATA=kron((1:1:r).', ones(n,1));
mode_STATA=repmat(["AIR"; "TRAIN"; "BUS"; "CAR"],r,1);
```

Here, I want to export `X_STATA`, `id_STATA`and `mode_STATA`.

How can I do this?

In particular, I want to make sure that the numbers after the comma of the entries of  `X_STATA` are well exported, without inappropriate approximations.

Comment: Write it to a file and make sure you use 17 significant digits for double values ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/35626253/2732801 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Matlab you can do the following:

```
writematrix(X_STATA, 'myfile.csv', 'precision', 17)
```

In Stata you import the data like this:

```
import delimited myfile.csv, asdouble
```

Comment: Thanks, should I do the same for `mode_STATA` which is a string?

Comment: Also, `writematrix` does not work in my Matlab (version 2017b). It tells me `Undefined function or variable 'writematrix'`

Comment: `writematrix` is the new unified function that handles both numeric and strings. An alternative is `dlmwrite`. Similar syntax but file name goes first and I think only handles numeric. You really need to study the help files. There is also the user-written function `dlmcell` which you can download for strings.