# How to import Stata dta file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, stata

I have a **dta** file that has been produced in Stata 16. All variables are "float". I would like to  import all the variables into a Matlab **mat** array (Matlab R2019b). How can I do that? I do not have Excel in my computer (hence, I cannot pass the variables to Excel and then load in Matlab).

Comment: Export as `csv` from Stata and then import in Matlab using `readmatrix()`.

Comment: ...Which is the opposite of what you asked in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57732293/).