# Why does Matlab ( using default short ) show a 0 in vector/matrix output with a scientific notation when it should show a 1?

Tags: matlab, zero, notation

If we take for example a vector of one line

```
>>m = linspace(0,100,11)
>>J = exp(m.^0.25)
```

we get

```
J =

  Columns 1 through 4

    1.0000    5.9197    8.2875   10.3848

  Columns 5 through 8

   12.3650   14.2841   16.1700   18.0385

  Columns 9 through 11

   19.8996   21.7599   23.6243
```

We get the right result in the first entry of the output matrix which is e^(0^0.25) = e^0 = 1

But if we take

```
>> J = exp(m.^2.5)
```

We get

```
J =

  1.0e+137 *

  Columns 1 through 4

    0.0000    2.1676       Inf       Inf

  Columns 5 through 8

       Inf       Inf       Inf       Inf

  Columns 9 through 11

       Inf       Inf       Inf
```

But e^(0^2.5) = e^0 = 1

I did not use matlab for a long time I don't have a good idea how this works, I first thought it could be a round off or a truncation or both, I looked up what the operation was and some documentation of the formats, I found that it does show the right result within the vector using the format longE :

```
>>format longE
```

which returns  1.000000000000000e+00

but then I checked the first matrix with the enry 0 ( Default format short) by using

```
>>J(1)
```

And it returned 1.

So the value in that entry is correct but it shows 0 , and a factor outside the matrix 1.0e+137 *
I don't get what is happening, why it shows a 0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When displaying a matrix in format long, MATLAB chooses a factor which is suitable for all entries. An example for the purpose of explanation:

```
k=10.^[1:10]

k =

   1.0e+10 *

    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0001    0.0010    0.0100    0.1000    1.0000
```

The first entry is a 10, but because of the factor of 10 000 000 000 it is not displayed. When you instead type in `k(1)` matlab will choose a format suitable for that number:

```
>> k(1)

ans =

    10
```

The standard output is "usually" good where all numbers in a similar magnitude. A workaround is to use `mat2str`.

```
>> mat2str([pi,10.^[1:20]])

ans =

    '[3.14159265358979 10 100 1000 10000 100000 1000000 10000000 100000000 1000000000 10000000000 100000000000 1000000000000 10000000000000 100000000000000 1e+15 1e+16 1e+17 1e+18 1e+19 1e+20]'
```

It displays up to 15 digits which is usually enough, but 17 digits would be required to display a double in full accuracy [(further information)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624419/matlab-vs-c-double-precision/35626253#35626253)

Comment: Lovely bonus solution!

Answer (score 2):

The numerical output format in MATLAB's Command Window is under user control which you can change from the [MATLAB Command Window Preferences](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/command-window-preferences.html).

What you are observing is the default behavior.

```
>> k=10.^[1:10];
>> k
k =
  1.0e+10 *
    0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0001  0.0010  0.0100  0.1000  1.0000
```

However, you can change the output format to use the floating point format:

```
>> format short e
>> k
k =
1.0000e+01   1.0000e+02   1.0000e+03   1.0000e+04   1.0000e+05   1.0000e+06   
1.0000e+07   1.0000e+08   1.0000e+09   1.0000e+10
```

You can also change it to use the "best of fixed or floating point format":

```
>> format short g
>> k
k =
10     100     1000    10000    1e+05    1e+06    1e+07    1e+08    1e+09    1e+10
```

See the [format](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) command on other available options. Explicitly printing your variables (using the `mat2str` command etc.) to see their full precision is not necessary, nor is it used by most MATLAB users. If you really want full precision you can use `format long e` or `format long g`.