# precision problems in matlab when using arrayfun

Tags: matlab, for-loop, precision

I am using matlab. I have a function `f(x)` and I want to apply `f(x)` to a set of values. So I wrote 2 codes. The first code is a simple for loop. At one point `x0`, inside this for loop, I find that `f(x0)=1.0000` and then I use `f(x0)-1=-4.7684e-07`.

My second code is using `arrayfun` on `f(x)`. And at the same input value `x0`, I found that the results is `1.0000` but `arrayfun(f,x0)-1=4.7684e-07`!

This error `4.7684e-07` looks tiny. But the for loop gives me a number below 1 and the `arrayfun` gives me a number above 1. This is really a big difference in my work, as my subsequent computations largely hinges on whether this number is below 1 or above 1, as this number is supposed to be a probability.

Now my question is: why `arrayfun` has such problem? There is no random numbers in my code, why `arrayfun` generates a different result than for loop? which one should I trust? Is there a way to avoid this kind of precision problem? Note that in this code, all of my variables are in `single` type. Is this causing the problem?

Comment: this seems indeed odd as `arrayfun` works like a loop under the hood. How about a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @max let me try to see if I can modify my original code.

Comment: Maybe the difference is already earlier and one of the x0 isn't exactly the same? When debugging your code, make sure to look at 17 significant digits. This is more than the 15 `format long` will show. Code you could use to print: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35626253/2732801

Comment: is there a reason why you work with `single`? This is indeed not much precision.

Comment: Please read [mre]. We cannot guess at what the problem is if we don’t know what you are doing. Your description is rich, but not complete. Show what you did, don’t tell what you did!

Answer (score 0):

addition and multiplication are not commutative under limited precision, and results depends on the order. For example, adding (a+b+c+d) is expected to give you different answers, up to the floating point round-off error, compared to (a+c+d+b). This is especially an issue in parallel computing where the orders of the accumulation from multiple parallel thread is not ensured.

You can either force the operation order or use higher precision, like double, to reduce this error.