# how can smallest floating point number be 2^(-126) , not 2^(-128)

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

Consider a 32 bit floating point number (IEEE 754) having 0-22 for mantissa(23 bits) , 23-30 for exponent(8 bits) , 31 for sign(1bit)
I want to find out the smallest positive number that can be stored.
I have been told answer is 1.18*10<sup>-38</sup> which is approx 2<sup>-126</sup>
My analysis is as follows
if we put all zeroes in mantissa and put all ones in exponent then the decimal equivalent would be 
 1.0 x 2<sup>-128</sup> = 2.93 x 10<sup>-39</sup>

Where am I going wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: As [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), "Exponents range from −126 to +127 because exponents of −127 (all 0s) and +128 (all 1s) are reserved for special numbers."

Comment: "I have been told answer is 1.18*10-38" <- That's not correct: that value is the smallest positive _normal_ number that's representable. The smallest positive number that's representable is `2^149`, or approximately `1.4*10^-45`.

Answer (score 5):

I think of IEEE-754 numbers as being divided into three main categories: specials, normals, and subnormals.  These categories are based on the value of the exponent, and there's also some substructure within each category.
Specials are those with the maximum exponent value, subnormals have an exponent that's the minimum, and normals are everything in between.  We can summarize things in a table (with the specific values here being those for single-precision `float`, as you asked about):

| exponent | significand | category | adjusted significand | adj. exp. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `FF` | nonzero | NaN | * | n/a |
| `FF` | 0 | infinity | n/a | n/a |
| `01` – `FE` | anything | normals | `(1)000000` – `(1)7fffff` | -126 – +127 |
| `00` | nonzero | subnormals | `000000` – `7fffff` | -126 |
| `00` | 0 | zero | 0 | n/a |

The key is that:

- Normal numbers have a 24-bit significand (popularly known as a "mantissa") where the leading bit is always 1 (and is therefore implicit) and an exponent in the range from -126 to +127 (which is `0x01` to `0xfe` or 1 to 254, minus the bias of 127).
- [Subnormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number) have a 23-bit significand where the leading bit is not necessarily 1 (and is therefore explicit) and an exponent of -126.

Now, you might think that for the subnormals, since the raw exponent is 0 and the exponent bias is 127, the actual exponent should be -127.  (That's what I thought for a long time, too.)  But that would leave a gap in the subnormals.  So the exponent for the subnormals is -126, and is one higher than you might have expected, and ends up matching the exponent for the smallest of the normals.

So what do these ranges work out to?

For normals, the maximum raw significand is `0x7fffff`, or `0xffffff` with the implicit 1 bit added, which as a fraction is `0x1.fffffe`, or 1.99999988079071044921875.  The minimum raw significand is `0x000000`, or `0x800000` with the implicit 1 bit added, which is `0x1.000000`, or 1.0.

For subnormals, the maximum raw significand is `0x7fffff`, which as a fraction is `0x0.fffffe`, or 0.99999988079071044921875.  The minimum raw significand is `0x000001`, which is `0x0.000002`, or 0.00000011920928955078125.

Putting this all together with the maximum and minimum exponent values, we have:

| threshold | derivation | decimal | hex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| max normal | 1.99999988 × 2<sup>127</sup> | 3.4028234663852885981e+38 | `0xf.fffff0E+31` |
| min normal | 1.0 × 2<sup>-126</sup> | 1.175494350822287508e-38 | `0x4.000000E-32` |
| max subnormal | 0.99999988 × 2<sup>-126</sup> | 1.175494210692441075e-38 | `0x3.fffff8E-32` |
| min subnormal | 0.000000119 × 2<sup>-126</sup> | 1.401298464324817071e-45 | `0x8.000000E-38` |

So when you heard that the smallest `float` was 1.18 × 10<sup>-38</sup>, obviously someone was talking about the smallest *normal* number, and ignoring the existence of the subnormals.  As you can see, the smallest of the subnormals is quite a bit smaller.

In this table we can also see why the exponent for the subnormals has to be -126, not -127.  The subnormals are supposed to cover the range between the smallest normal and zero.  With an exponent of -126, they do that uniformly and well.  If the exponent for the subnormals were -127, on the other hand, the largest subnormal would be 0.9999998 × 2<sup>-127</sup> = 5.877471053462205377e-39 or `0x1.fffffcE-32`, which is already halfway down the slope to zero (so to speak), with the rest of the subnormals jammed in below that, leaving a "big" gap between 1.175e-38 and 5.877e-39.  Wikipedia has a [nice picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Denormalized_numbers_on_a_line.svg) from the "subnormal number" page illustrating the way the subnormal numbers fill the gap near 0.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827176/) for more on how IEEE-754 floating-point values are constructed.

---

Footnote: Where I've used a notation like `0x1.fffffe` in this answer, that's a base-16 fraction, which of course is not something your C compiler would accept.  And then `0xf.fffffE+31` is hexadecimal scientific notation, where the exponent is a power of 16, and the `E` is *not* a hexadecimal digit that's part of the significand.  This is sort of like the `printf`/`scanf` format `%a`, although `%a` uses `p` to mark its exponent, which is a power of 2.

Comment: That's a very good explanation of IEEE754.

Comment: @SteveSummit can you write binary form of "minimum raw significand", my brain a little bit confused. For the maximum raw significand part, "0x1.fffffe" `why not` "0x1.7ffff"? In addition, minimum raw significand with binary form = `00000000 00000000 0000000 = 0x00000`, 
What does "implicit 1 bit" added mean? will it; `1 + 23bit = 1 00000000 00000000 0000000 = 0x800000?` I need more details for binary representation instead hex

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki That form `0x1.fffffe` looks weird, because 23 is not a multiple of 4.  It's equivalent to `0b1.11111111111111111111111`.  (You asked about `0x1.7ffff`.  That would be `0b1.011111111111111111111111`, which is different.)

Comment: For a normal significand like `0b1.10101010101010101010101` or `0b1.11111111111111111111111`, there are 24 bits, but the leading bit (to the left of the `.`) is *always* 1, so it's not explicitly stored — it is "implicit" or "hidden". (Only the 23 bits to the right of the `.` are explicitly stored.). For a subnormal number like `0b0.10101010101010101010101` or `0b0.00000000000000000000000`, again, only the 23 bits to the right of the `.` are stored. The exponent value explicitly tells you which form you're using. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number .

Comment: The minimum nonzero significand, which is among the subnormals, is `0b0.00000000000000000000001`, or `0x0.000002` in hexadecimal. (That's confusing, too: maybe think of it as `0b0.000000000000000000000010`. But only the 23 bits `00000000000000000000001` are stored, which as a raw 23-bit hexadecimal integer we'd express as `0x000001` .)

Comment: "In subnormal numbers have a 23-bit significand where the leading bit is not necessarily 1 (and is therefore explicit)...", So in subnormal form has msb is stored right? So why do we always subtract 1 from the bias value in subnormal forms? Is it because we stored the leading bit? What does it  "explicitly stored" mean for subnormal values? @SteveSummit

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki My statement "subnormal numbers have a 23-bit significand where the leading bit is not necessarily 1 (and is therefore explicit)" is confusing, and I'm no longer sure it's meaningful.  You could also say that the leading bit of a subnormal number is always 0 (and is therefore not stored).

Comment: The reason for "subtracting 1" from the exponent — that is, the reason that the exponent for single-precision subnormals is -126 instead of -127 — is explained in my answer, in the paragraph beginning "In this table we can also see why".  It has nothing directly to do with storing or not storing the leading bit.  It has to be that way to make the math work out.

Comment: One of the things that confuses me is this: "The 23-bit fraction combined with the implicit leading significand bit provides 24 bits of precision", What does it means when says '24 bits of precision', why denormalized has 23 bits of precision when leading bits 0, why not 24 bit? Doesn't the 0 value on the left have any significance in precision? @SteveSummit

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki Excellent question.  A subnormal number does *not* have full precision.  For a normal, full-precision number, there are 24 bits of significance: 23 explicitly stored, plus 1 hidden bit.  But for a subnormal number, there are between 0 and 23 bits of precision, all explicitly stored.  `0b0.11111111111111111111111` and `0b0.10101010101010101010101` both have 23 bits.  `0b0.00000000001111111111111` and `0b0.00000000001010101010101` have 13 bits.  `0b0.00000000000000000000001` has 1 bit.  `0b0.00000000000000000000000` has 0 bits.

Comment: The "significant portion" of a number is basically from the first nonzero bit/digit, to the last.  Leading 0's don't count, and trailing 0's don't count.  And when we say that a format provides "N bits of significance", we really mean "*up to* N bits".  For example, the normalized significand `0b1.11111111111110000000000` only has 14 bits of significance (even though it has room for 10 more).  Similarly, the nonnormalized significand `0b0.11111111111110000000000` has 13 bits of significance (and room for 10 more).

Comment: Thank u for great explanation @SteveSummit, can you give some information about ULP with comparing two number?

Answer (score 2):

If you put all ones in exponent you will get `NaN` if mantissa is non-zero or infinite if mantissa is 0. [Wikipedia IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). Also your minimal value is inside [Denormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) space when exponent is binary equal to 0.

Comment: I wrote a comprehensive tutorial about denormal numbers at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341395/what-is-a-subnormal-floating-point-number/53203428#53203428

Answer (score -2):

Although 8 bits exponent means -127 to +128 but two case is reserved for special values (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Special_values)), so the most negative exponent is -126.

BTW, it's impossible to store -128 in 8 bits in `Two's Complement` system which is the base system used in exponent of `IEEE 754`.

Comment: IEEE 754 does not use the two's complement system to store the exponent. (And I think you meant "8 bits" rather than "8 bytes".)

Comment: In the system that is actually used to store the exponent, they could have chosen any consecutive range of 254 exponent values (256 minus two special cases, all zeros and all ones).

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Yea, i meant bits. I've corrected it. IEEE754 use a biased  two's complement so there isn't any negative number in first sight.

Comment: I think , you mean that in IEEE754 there is +zero and -zero so -1 to -126 on one side and +1 to +128 on another side.
That also explains biggest number as approx 2^128 = 3.4 X 10^38

Comment: @user1371666: There are one zero in exponent because it uses biased version of two's complement system, so the biggest exponent is +127 and largest normalized number is (2−2^−23) × 2^127 ≈ ±3.4×10^38 (Where mantissa is all 1, sign bit is 1 and exponent is 11111110)

Comment: @SuB: Two's complement is *not* involved *at all* in the encoding of the IEEE 754 exponent. For normal numbers, the exponent is encoded with a simple bias: `127` for the binary32 format ("single precision"), `1023` for binary64 ("double precision"). "biased version of two's complement" makes little sense.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Yea,when you encode on the fly you will not sense the role of two's complement but when you are writing a compiler or assembler to generate `opcode` you first calculate two's complement of exponent then add 127 to make it biased and then store it. In fact there are two ways to encode exponent: 1) Add 127 and then calculate binary representation 2) Calculate binary representation and then add 127. Human use the first method but computers use the second one.

Comment: @SuB No, two's complement is not involved at all in the encoding of the IEEE 754.