# Time Complexity for Power Function in C

Tags: c, time-complexity

For the Power function below, time limit has exceeded.
I can see other solutions to this problem here, but wanted to know why time limit exceeds with my implementation.

```
double Power(double x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    if (x == 0) return 0;

    double result = x;
    int temp = n;
    if (temp < 0)
    {
        temp = temp * -1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < temp; i++)
    {
        result *= x;
    }
    if (n < 0)
    {
        result = 1 / result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This takes O(n) time.  There's a method that takes O(log(n)) time.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is very slow for large values of `n`. You're doing `n` multiplications to get the power, so this is O(n) complexity.

```
p = x*x*x*...*x
    \---------/
      n times
```

You can speed up the calculation by grouping the values. For example you could calculate the square of `x` and then multiply that value `n/2` times with itself (Note that you may need a single `x` in the end if `n` is odd).

```
x2 = x*x
p = x2*x2*...*x2 (*x)
    \----------/
      n/2 times
```

With this you only needed (n+1)/2+1 multiplications, which is O(n/2) and twice as fast in the limit of large `n`.

As you might guess, you can even further group the values and reuse those grouped powers, which leads to a O(log(n)) time complexity as @dbush pointed out in the comment to your question:

```
double Power(double x, int n) {
    double result = 1.0;
    double group;

    if ( x == 0.0 ) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    if ( n < 0 ) {
        n = -n;
        group = 1.0/x;
    } else {
        group = x;
    }

    while ( n > 0 ) {
        if ( n % 2 ) {
            result *= group;
        }
        n = n/2;
        group *= group;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This algorithm keeps squaring the value of the group and multiply that group value to the result if needed.

**Note** There is a constant time O(1) implementation of the power function (e.g. the `pow` from `math.h`). This makes use of the fact that doubles only have a limited precision. The power can be written as

```
pow(x,n) = exp(n*log(x))
```

and the exponential `exp` as well as the natural logarithm `log` can be calulated in constant time (see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70602547/could-anyone-tell-clearly-how-to-find-the-exponents-with-fractional-values-or-de) for example). For small integer values of n, the above algorithm is faster though.