# How can I know in advance which real numbers would have an imprecise representation using float variables in C?

Tags: c, floating-point

I know that the number 159.95 cannot be precisely represented using float variables in C.

For example, considering the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float x = 159.95;
    printf("%f\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs 159.949997.

I would like to know if there is some way to know in advance which real value (in decimal system) would be represented in an imprecise way like the 159.95 number.

Best regards.

Comment: Basically all numbers that need more than `24` bits, ie... those that are not a multiple of `1/(2^24)` or `.000000059604644775390625` (might be `23` or `25`, I'm not sure; it is different for `float`, `double`, `long double`) ... and it changes with the range -- it's different for large and small numbers (`45234523674` or `0.000000000000000006756542`). Read [IEEE 754 Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

Comment: Are you familiar with IEEE 754 standard?

Comment: Also, in the absence of a **strong reason** otherwise, always use `double` for floating-point.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes. I know it.
But I'm just starting to learn how to program and digital stuff.
It is not obvious for me, after reading the standard, how to determine when a real number (in decimal system) would be imprecisely represented. Please, let me know what I have missed from the standard.

Comment: @pmg They don't need to be "large". 1.000000059604644775390625 is already large enough to not be representable as a float.

Comment: @Zaratruta Naively, you could create a list of *all* floats possible (32 bits - a bit over 4 million entries) and look up in there. For `double`s won't be practical though.

Comment: A simple answer would be to assume they are all imprecise, and work accordingly, especially with comparison tests. And in the example 159.95 posted, if you need 9 significant digits then `float` is inadequate.

Comment: @WeatherVane. Yes. When I develop programs, I assume that.
However, I would like to understand the phenomenon in a deeper way.

Comment: Put it this way: of the *infinity* of floating point values there are, only about 2^32 can be exactly represented.

Comment: use printf("%.2f\n", x); for float and printf("%.2lf\n", x); for double. You will get output 159.95

Comment: There are several more answers to this question — I suppose I should vote to close as a duplicate — at [How to determine w/o conversions that a given floating constant can be represented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68835588)

Comment: Given that there an infinite number or _real values_ that cannot be represented using a _finite_ 32 bit representation, is there really any benefit in picking out the insignificant number of values that can be exactly represented?  This is true of any representation - most _real_ values are also not precisely represented in decimal either - no matter how many digits you use.  Real values are continuous; any number system representation with a finite number of digits is discrete.

Comment: @SteveSummit. In my point of view, it is not the same question.
My question here is how can we determine in advance which number can be precisely represented.

Comment: @Clifford. The benefit is understanding. And everithing that can follow from this.

Comment: @Zaratruta Floating point numbers are fascinating, and rewarding to understand.  Two other questions I've found particularly instructive are [bitwise splitting the mantissa of a IEEE 754 double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207580) and [how can smallest floating point number be 2^(-126) , not 2^(-128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153699).

Comment: Yes, that is my point.  If you understand the maths, you realise the futility of this exercise. _real_ numbers and _decimal_ representation of numbers are not the same thing.  You seem to be equating them. The coincidence of an exact decimal with a particular binary representation is not particularly useful.  What is useful to understand is the number of _decimal significant figures_ are preserved without change in a round-trip conversion from decimal to binary and back.  For `float` it is 6.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310276/decimal-precision-of-floats

Comment: Yet more good discussion at [Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is some way to know in advance which real value... would be represented in an imprecise way

The short and only partly facetious answer is... all of them!

There are roughly 2^32 = 4294967296 values of type `float`.  And there are an uncountably infinite number of real numbers.  So, for a randomly-chosen real number, the chance that it can be exactly represented as a value of type `float` is 4294967296/∞, which is 0.

If you use type `double`, there are approximately 2^64 = 18446744073709551616 of those, so the chance that a randomly-chosen real number can be exactly represented as a `double` is 18446744073709551616/∞, which is again... 0.

I realize I'm not answering quite the question you asked, but in general, it's usually a bad idea to use binary floating-point types as if they were an exact representation of decimal fractions.  Attempts to assume that they're ever an exact representation usually lead to trouble.  In general, it's best to assume that floating-point types are an imperfect (approximate) realization of of real numbers, period (that is, without assuming decimal).  If you never assume they're exact (which for true real numbers, they virtually never are), you'll never get into trouble in cases where you thought they'd be exact, but they weren't.

[Footnote 1: As Eric P. reminds in a comment, there's no such thing as a "randomly-chosen real number", which is why this is a partially facetious answer.]

[Footnote 2: I now see your comment where you say that you do assume they are all imprecise, but that you would "like to understand the phenomenon in a deeper way", in which case my answer does you no good, but hopefully some of the others do.  I can especially commend Martin Rosenau's answer, which goes straight to the heart of the matter: a rational number is representable exactly in base 2 if and only if its reduced denominator is a pure power of 2, or stated another way, has only 2's in its prime factorization.  That's why, if you take any number you can actually store in a `float` or `double`, and print it back out using `%f` and enough digits, with a properly-written `printf`, you'll notice that the numbers always end in things like ...625 or ...375.  Binary fractions are like the English rulers still used in the U.S.: everything is halves and quarters and eights and sixteenths and thirty-seconds and sixty-fourths.]

Comment: The same can be said for integers.

Comment: @stark Unless we are picking from a specific range.

Comment: Re “for a randomly-chosen real number”: No uniform distribution can be defined on the real numbers (nor even on the integers), so some other distribution must be specified. In infinitely many such distributions, the probability a chosen number is representable is non-zero.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I meant to concede that this was a partially-facetious answer.  Thanks for the reminder (and the reasoning).

Comment: There are uncountably infinite different real numbers, but there are only a countable infinite subset of them that we can represent thru an algorithm. Most of them, we'll never ever be able to represent in a computer in whatever format. We just can't compute them! Of course, if we're able to give a decimal representation of the real, it falls in the countable set.

Answer (score 4):

Succinctly, for the format most commonly used for `float`, a number is exactly representable if and only if it is representable as an integer *F* times a power of two, 2<sup>*E*</sup> such that:

- the magnitude of *F* is less than 2<sup>24</sup>, and
- –149 ≤ *E* < 105.

More generally, C 2018 5.2.4.2.2 specifies the characteristics of floating-point types. A *floating-point number* is represented as *s*•*b*<sup>*e*</sup>•sum(*f*<sub>*k*</sub> *b*<sup>−*k*</sup>, 1 ≤ *k* ≤ *p*), where:

- *s* is a sign, +1 or −1,
- *b* is a fixed base chosen by the C implementation, often 2,
- *e* is an exponent, which is an integer between a minimum *e*<sub>min</sub> and a maximum *e*<sub>max</sub>, chosen by the C implementation,
- *p* is the precision, the number of base-*b* digits in the significand, and
- *f*<sub>*k*</sub> are digits in base-*b*, nonnegative integers less than *b*.

The *significand* is the fraction portion of the representation, sum(*f*<sub>*k*</sub> *b*<sup>−*k*</sup>, 1 ≤ *k* ≤ *p*). It is written as a sum so that we can express the variable number of digits it may have. (*p* is a variable set by the C implementation, not by the programmer using the C implementation.) When we write it out a significand in base *b*, it can be a numeral, such as .001110101001100101010110<sub>2</sub> for a 24-bit significand in base 2. Note that, in the this form (and the sum), the significand has all its digits after the radix point.

To make it slightly easier to tell if a number is in this format, we can adjust the scale so the significand is an integer instead of having digits after the radix point: *s*•*b*<sup>*e*−*p*</sup>•sum(*f*<sub>*k*</sub> *b*<sup>*p*−*k*</sup>, 1 ≤ *k* ≤ *p*). This changes the above significand from .001110101001100101010110<sub>2</sub> to 001110101001100101010110<sub>2</sub>. Since it has *p* digits, it is always a non-negative integer less than *b*<sup>*p*</sup>.

Now we can figure out if a finite number is representable in this format:

- Get *b*, *p*, *e*<sub>min</sub>, and *e*<sub>max</sub> for the target C implementation. If it uses IEEE-754 binary32 for `float`, then *b* is 2, *p* is 24, *e*<sub>min</sub> is −125, and *e*<sub>max</sub> is 128. When `<float.h>` is included, these are defined as `FLT_RADIX`, `FLT_MANT_DIGITS`, `FLT_MIN_EXP`, and `FLT_MAX_EXP`.
- Ignore the sign. Write the absolute value of number as a rational number *n*/*d* in simplest form. If it is an integer, let *d* be 1.
- If *d* is not a power of *b*, the number is not representable in the format.
- If *n* is a multiple of *b* greater than or equal to *b*<sup>*p*</sup>, divide it by *b* and multiply *d* by *d* until *n* is not a multiple or is less than *b*<sup>*p*</sup>.
- If *n* is greater than or equal to *b*<sup>*p*</sup>, the number is not representable in the format.
- Let *e* be such that 1/*d* = *b*<sup>*e*−*p*</sup>. If *e*<sub>min</sub> ≤ *e* ≤ *e*<sub>max</sub>, the number is representable in the format. Otherwise, it is not.

Some floating-point formats might not support subnormal numbers, in which *f*<sub>1</sub> is zero. This is indicated by `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM` being defined to be zero and would require modifications to the above.

Comment: Excellent write-up. For IEEE-754 `binary32` I verified that the stated bounds for `E` are tight.

Comment: @njuffa: Thanks. There are three or more opportunities for off-by-one errors in those, so I was worried about them. (IEEE-754 exponent bounds are 1−127 = −126 and 254−127 = 127, C expresses them with the significand scaled down by 2, and then there is the scaling to make the significand an integer.)

Comment: @njuffa: Of course, I had the exponent sense of d negated in d = b^(e-p), since it is the denominator. I corrected that to 1/d = b^(e-p). Plenty of opportunities for errors, sigh.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know if there is some way to know in advance which real value (in decimal system) would be represented in an imprecise way like the 159.95 number.

In general, floating point numbers can only represent numbers whose denominator is a power of 2.

To check if a number can be represented as floating point value (of any floating-point type) at all, take the decimal digits after the decimal point, interpret them as number and check if they can be divided by 5^n while n is the number of digits:

159.95 => 95, 2 digits => `95%(5*5) = 20` => Cannot be represented as floating-point value

Counterexample:

159.625 => 625, 3 digits => `625%(5*5*5) = 0` => Can be represented as floating-point value

You also have to consider the fact that floating-point values only have a limited number of digits after the decimal point:

In principle, 123456789 can be represented by a floating-point value exactly (it is an integer), however `float` does not have enough bits!

To check if an integer value can be represented by `float` exactly, divide the number by 2 until the result is odd. If the result is < 2^24, the number can be represented by `float` exactly.

In the case of a rational number, first do the "divisible by 5^n" check described above. Then multiply the number by 2 until the result is an integer. Check if it is < 2^24.

Comment: Nice answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, a `float` is an IEEE754 binary32 float (this is not guaranteed by spec and may be different on some compilers/systems). This data type specifies a 24-bit significand; this means that if you write the number in binary, it should require no more than 24 bits excluding trailing zeros.

[159.95's binary representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=159.95+to+binary) is 10011111.11110011001100110011... with repeating 0011 forever, so it requires an infinite number of bits to represent precisely with a binary format.

Other examples:

1073741760 has a binary representation of 111111111111111111111111000000. It has 30 bits in that representation, but only 24 significant bits (since the remainder are trailing zero bits). It has an exact float representation.

1073741761 has a binary representation of 111111111111111111111111000001. It has 30 significant bits and cannot be represented exactly as a float.

0.000000059604644775390625 has a binary representation of 0.000000000000000000000001. It has one significant bit and can be represented exactly.

0.750000059604644775390625 has a binary representation of 0.110000000000000000000001, which is 24 significant bits. It can be represented exactly as a float.

1.000000059604644775390625 has a binary representation of 1.000000000000000000000001, which is 25 significant bits. It cannot be represented exactly as a float.

Another factor (which applies to very large and very small numbers) is that the exponent is limited to the -126 to +127 range. With some handwaving around denormal values and other special cases, this generally allows values ranging from roughly 2<sup>-126</sup> to slightly under 2<sup>128</sup>.

Comment: @chtz Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know if there is some way to know in advance which real value (in decimal system) would be represented in an imprecise way like the 159.95 number.

In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71118404/how-can-i-know-in-advance-which-real-numbers-would-have-an-imprecise-representat/71118756#71118756) I semiseriously answered "all of them",
but let's look at it another way.  Specifically, let's look at
which numbers *can* be exactly represented.

The key fact to remember is that *floating point formats use binary*.
(The major, popular formats, anyway.)  So the numbers that can be
represented exactly are the ones with exact *binary* representations.

Here is a table of a few of the single-precision `float` values
that can be represented exactly, specifically the seven
contiguous values near 1.0.
I'm going to show them as hexadecimal fractions, binary
fractions, and decimal fractions.
(That is, along each horizontal row, all three values are exactly
the same, just represented in different bases.  But note that the
fractional hexadecimal and binary representations I'm using here
are *not* directly acceptable in C.)

| hexadecimal | binary | decimal | delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x0.fffffd | 0b0.111111111111111111111101 | 0.999999821186065673828125 | 5.96e-08 |
| 0x0.fffffe | 0b0.111111111111111111111110 | 0.999999880790710449218750 | 5.96e-08 |
| 0x0.ffffff | 0b0.111111111111111111111111 | 0.999999940395355224609375 | 5.96e-08 |
| 0x1.000000 | 0b1.00000000000000000000000 | 1.000000000000000000000000 |  |
| 0x1.000002 | 0b1.00000000000000000000001 | 1.000000119209289550781250 | 1.19e-07 |
| 0x1.000004 | 0b1.00000000000000000000010 | 1.000000238418579101562500 | 1.19e-07 |
| 0x1.000006 | 0b1.00000000000000000000011 | 1.000000357627868652343750 | 1.19e-07 |

There are several things to notice about this table:

- The decimal numbers look pretty weird.
- The hexadecimal and binary numbers look pretty *normal*, and show pretty clearly that single-precision floating point has 24 bits of precision.
- If you look at the decimal column, the precision seems to be about equivalent to 7 decimal digits.
- It's clearly not *exactly* 7 digits, though.
- The difference between consecutive values less than 1.0 is about 0.00000005, and greater than 1.0 is twice that, about 0.00000010.  (More on this later.)

Here is a similar table for type `double`.
(I'm showing fewer columns because there's not enough room
horizontally for everything.)

| hexadecimal | decimal | delta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x0.ffffffffffffe8 | 0.99999999999999966693309261245303787291049957275390625 | 1.11e-16 |
| 0x0.fffffffffffff0 | 0.99999999999999977795539507496869191527366638183593750 | 1.11e-16 |
| 0x0.fffffffffffff8 | 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875 | 1.11e-16 |
| 0x1.0000000000000 | 1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |  |
| 0x1.0000000000001 | 1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625 | 2.22e-16 |
| 0x1.0000000000002 | 1.0000000000000004440892098500626161694526672363281250 | 2.22e-16 |
| 0x1.0000000000003 | 1.0000000000000006661338147750939242541790008544921875 | 2.22e-16 |

You can see right away that type `double` has much better precision:
53 bits, or about 15 decimal digits' worth instead of 7, and with a much
finer spacing between "adjacent" numbers.

What does it mean for these numbers to be "contiguous" or
"adjacent"?  Aren't real numbers continuous?  Yes, true real
numbers are continuous, but we're not looking at true real
numbers: we're looking at finite-precision floating point, and we
are, literally, seeing the finite limit of the precision here.
In type `float`, there simply is no value — no representable
value, that is — between 1.00000000 and 1.00000012.
In type `double`, there is no value between 1.00000000000000000
and 1.00000000000000022.

So let's go back to your question, asking whether there's "some way
to know which decimal values are represented in a precise or imprecise way."

If you look at ten decimal values between 1 and 2:

```
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
```

the answer is, only one of them is exactly representable in binary: 1.5.

If you break the interval down into 100 fractions, like this:

```
1.01
1.02
1.03
1.04
1.05
…
1.95
1.96
1.97
1.98
1.99
```

it turns out there are three fractions you can represent exactly:
.25, .50, and .75, corresponding to
¼, ½, and ¾.

If we looked at three-digit decimal fractions, there are at most
seven of them we can represent: .125, .250, .375, .500, .625, .750, and .875.  These correspond to eighths, that is, ordinary
fractions with 8 in the denominator.

I said "at most seven" because it's not true (none of these
estimates are true) for all ranges of numbers.  Remember,
precision is finite, and digits to the left of the decimal part
— that is, in the integral part of your numbers — count against
your precision budget, too.  So it turns out that if you were to
look at the range, say, 4000000–4000001, and tried to subdivide
it, you would find that you could represent 4000000.25 and
4000000.50 as type `float`, but *not* 4000000.125 or 4000000.375.
You can't really see it if you look at the decimal
representation, but what's happening inside is that type `float`
has exactly 24 binary *bits* of available precision, and the
integer part 4000000 uses up 22 of those bits, so you've only got
two bits left over for the fractional part, and with two bits you
can do halves and quarters, but not eighths.

You're probably noticing a pattern by now: the fractions we've
looked at so far that *can* be be represented exactly in binary
involve halves, quarters, and eights, and if we looked further,
this pattern would continue: sixteenths, thirty-seconds,
sixty-fourths, etc.  And this should come as no real surprise:
just as in decimal the "exact" fractions involve tenths,
hundredths, thousandths, etc.; when we move to binary (base 2) the fractions
all involve powers of two.  ½ in binary is `0b0.1`.
¼ and ¾ are `0b0.01` and `0b0.11`.
⅜ and ⅝ are `0b0.011` and `0b0.101`.

What about a fraction like 1/3?  You can't represent it exactly
in binary, but since you can't represent it in decimal, either,
this doesn't tend to bother us too much.  In decimal it's the
infinitely repeating fraction 0.333333…, and in binary it's the
infinitely-repeating fraction `0b0.0101010101…`.

But then we come to the humble fraction 1/10, or one tenth.
This obviously *can* be represented as a decimal fraction — 0.1 —
but it turns out that it *cannot* be represented exactly in binary.
In binary it's the infinitely-repeating fraction `0b0.0001100110011…`.
And this is why, as we saw above, you can't represent most of the other
"single digit" decimal fractions 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, …, either
(with the notable exception of 0.5), and you can't represent most
of the double-digit decimal fractions 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, …,
or most of the triple-digit decimal fractions, etc.

So returning once more to your question of which decimal
fractions can be represented exactly, we can say:

- For single-digit fractions 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, …, we can exactly represent .5, and to be charitable we can say that we can also represent .0, so that's two out of ten, or 20%.
- For double-digit fractions 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, …, we can exactly represent .00, 0.25, 0.50, and 0.75, so that's four out of a hundred, or 4%.
- For three-digit fractions 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, …, we can exactly represent the eight fractions involving eighths, so that's 8/1000 = 0.8%.

So while there are some decimal fractions we can represent
exactly, there aren't very many, and the percentage seems to be
going down as we add more digits. :-(

The fact — and depending on your point of view it's either an
unfortunate fact or a sad fact or a perfectly normal fact —
is that most decimal fractions can *not* be represented exactly
in binary and so can *not* be represented exactly using computer
floating point.
The numbers that can be represented exactly using computer
floating point, although they can all be exactly converted into
numerically equivalent decimal fractions, end up converting to
rather weird-looking numbers for the most part, with lots of digits, as we saw above.
(In fact, for type `float`, which internally has 24 bits of
significance, the exact decimal conversions end up having up to
24 decimal digits.  And the fractions always end in 5.)

One last point concerns the spacing *between* these "contiguous",
exactly-representable binary fractions.  In the examples I've
shown, why is there tighter spacing for numbers less than 1.0
than for numbers greater than 1.0?

The answer lies in an earlier statement that "precision is
finite, and digits to the left of the decimal part count against
your precision budget, too".  Switching to decimal fractions for
a moment, if I told you you had exactly 7 significant decimal
digits to work with, you could represent

```
1234.567
1234.568
1234.569
```

and

```
12345.67
12345.68
12345.69
```

but you could not represent

```
12345.678
```

because that would require 8 significant digits.

Stated another way, for numbers between 1000 and 10000 you can
have three more digits after the decimal point, but for numbers
from 10000 to 100000 you can only have two.  Mathematicians call
these intervals like 1000-10000 and 10000-100000 *decades*,
and within each decade, all the numbers have the same number of
fractional digits for a given precision, and the same exponents:
1.000000×10<sup>3</sup> – 1.999999×10<sup>3</sup>,
1.000000×10<sup>4</sup> – 1.999999×10<sup>4</sup>, etc.
(This usage is rather different than ordinary usage, in which the
word "decade" refers to a period of 10 years.)

But for binary floating point, once again, the intervals of
interest involve powers of 2, not 10.  (In binary, some computer
scientists call these intervals *binades*, by analogy with "decades".)
The interesting intervals are from 1 to 2, 2–4, 4–8, 8–16, etc.
For numbers between 1 and 2, you've got 1 bit to the left of the
decimal point (really the "binary point"), so in single precision
you've got 23 bits left over to use for the fractional part to the right.
But for numbers between 2 and 4, you've got 2 bits to the left,
so you've only got 22 bits to use for the fraction.

This works in the other direction, too: for numbers between
½ and 1, you don't need any bits to the left of the binary
point, so you can use all 24 for the fraction to the right.
(Below ½ it gets even more interesting).  So that's why we
saw twice the precision (numbers half the size in the "delta"
column) for numbers just below 1.0 than for numbers just above.
We'd see similar shifts in available precision when crossing all the other
powers of two: 2.0, 4.0, 8.0, …, and also ½, ¼,
⅛, etc.

---

This has been a rather long answer, longer than I had intended.
Thanks for reading.
Hopefully now you have a better appreciation for which numbers can be
exactly represented in binary floating point, and why most of them can't.